# Background image still issue on php htdocs after every tries

Tags: html, image, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've tried all the syntax but the issue remains the same:

```
#body
{
    position: relative;
}

#body::before
{
  background: url(http://hirem.edu.vn/asset/client/images/bg1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    -moz-filter: blur(3px);
    -o-filter: blur(3px);
    -ms-filter: blur(3px);
    filter: blur(3px);
}
```

The above code is working just for one php file when I use this code on other css with other id like bg, background instead of body id. The code didn't work. Just working for one php and css. I just changed the id name nothing more.

I've tried:

```
background-image: url("../img/etc.jpg")
background:url(http:etc/etc/jpg)
background-image:url("/img/etc.jpg")
```

Everything. Before converting into PHP extension. It was working fine with all .html file not for one.

Comment: Have you tried the absolute path like your first example that works? Seems like a path/css/html issue, not PHP. What is the response when the resource is requested?

Comment: if path issue than why the same code is working with other css and html. I just copied the same and edit the id name with respect to that html. Even i didn't change the picture/path.

Comment: No response shows. I didn't host yet. Just white background shows.

Comment: I tried this path "http://localhost/experimentalCopy/img/graduation.jpg" its working fine on firefox but not on chrome. Firefox gets the image but chrome shows nothing. As i told that working code on first php also working in chrome

Comment: Thank you. Issue resolved. it was just pathetic adblock issue. i just disabled and code is working fine -_-